# MySQL get rows but prefer one column value over another

Tags: sql, mysql

A bit of a strange one, I want to write a MySQL query that will get results from a table, but prefer one value of a column over another, ie

```
id   name    value   prioirty
1    name1   value1  NULL
2    name1   value1  1
3    name2   value2  NULL
4    name3   value3  NULL
```

So here name1 has two entries, but one has a prioirty of 1. I want to get all the values from the table, but prefer the values with whatever priorty I'm after.

The results I'd be after would be

```
id   name    value   prioirty
2    name1   value1  1
3    name2   value2  NULL
4    name3   value3  NULL
```

An equivalent way of saying it would be 'get all rows from the table, but prefer rows with a priority of x'.

Comment: This is a little under-specified.  By 'prefer' do you mean: "if a row exists with priority x then retrieve that row; otherwise ... what?"  The "otherwise" can have several different definitions depending on whether there can be multiple such "otherwise" rows.  You need to fully define the desired "otherwise" results.

Comment: Otheriwse return the other row with of same name, but with a prioirty of NULL.

At least one row with name1, name2, name3 will always exist in the table. It just happens that there may be other versions (with the same name), but with different prioirty values.

I'm trying to grab what I need without doing two queries (one for prioirty = null and one for prioirty = x) then comparing the two result sets.

Cheers,
Gaz.

Comment: Any idea on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848693/mysql-get-rows-but-prefer-one-column-value-over-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redesign your table first.

It should be:

```
YourTable (Id, Name, Value)
YourTablePriority (PriorityId, Priority, Id)
```

Update:

```
select * from YourTable a 
where a.Id not in 
   (select b.Id from YourTablePriority b)
```

This should work in sql server, you may need a little change to make it work in mysql.

Comment: What's the point? And what difference would it make to the soultion?

Comment: Your table will be normalized and there will be no NULL values

Comment: It will also remove the duplicate name1 and value1

Comment: You will then be able to select all names with no priorities in the the priority table.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
     T1.id,
     T1.name,
     T1.value,
     T1.priority
FROM
     My_Table T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Table T2 ON
     T2.name = T1.name AND
     T2.priority > COALESCE(T1.priority, -1)
WHERE
     T2.id IS NULL
```

This also allows you to have multiple priority levels with the highest being the one that you want to return (if you had a 1 and 2, the 2 would be returned).

I will also say though that it does seem like there are some design problems in the DB. My approach would have been:

My_Table (id, name)
My_Values (id, priority, value)
with an FK on id to id. PKs on id in My_Table and id, priority in My_Values. Of course, I'd use appropriate table names too.

Comment: @Tom, when I run this I on Gary's data set, I get results for only "name2" and "name3" -- the interesting case is excluded because the WHERE clause is false wherever T2.priority is actually defined...

Comment: Whoops... the >= should just be >. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT id, name, value, priority FROM 
table_name GROUP BY name ORDER BY priority
```

Although not having a database in front of me I can't test it...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the `value` of a `name` given a *specific* `priority`, or the `value` associated with a NULL `priority`.  (You do not necessarily want the `MAX(priority)` that exists.)

Yes, you've got some awkward design issues which you should address, but let's solve the problem you do have at present (and you can later migrate to the problem you ought to have :) ):

```
mysql> SET @priority = 1;  -- the priority we want, if recorded

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM "
       SELECT
         t0.*
       FROM
         t t0
       LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT DISTINCT name, priority FROM t WHERE priority = ?) t1
           ON t0.name = t1.name
       WHERE
         t0.priority = t1.priority
           OR
         t1.priority IS NULL
       ";

mysql> EXECUTE stmt USING @priority;
+----+-------+--------+----------+
| id | name  | value  | priority |
+----+-------+--------+----------+
|  2 | name1 | valueX |        1 | 
|  3 | name2 | value2 |     NULL | 
|  4 | name3 | value3 |     NULL | 
+----+-------+--------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(Note that I changed the prioritized `value` of "name1" to "valueX" in the above -- your original formulation had identical `value` values for "name1" regardless of priority, which made it hard for me to understand why you cared to discriminate one from the other.)