# Mysql SELECT and return multiple rows, but prefer one column value over another when present

Tags: mysql, sql

So i'm looking to write a MySQL query that will return a result set that, when a particular column has a particular row value, it will return that row instead of another near duplicate row but otherwise return results like normal.

Okay, here is my table

```
id   name    value   another

1    name1   value1  
2    name1   value1  foo
3    name2   value2  
4    name3   value3
```

and results should be (if foo is present):

```
id   name    value   another

2    name1   value1  foo
3    name2   value2  
4    name3   value3
```

I did find this example: [MySQL get rows but prefer one column value over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848693/mysql-get-rows-but-prefer-one-column-value-over-another) but couldn't figure out how to adapt it to my needs...

I hope I'm making sense! No sleep in two days ain't good for attempts at elucidation! Also I'm very sorry if this has already been asked, i searched for a good long time but just didn't have the vocabulary to find any results...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to upvote you. Unfortunately either through my ignorance or through my poor communication, i couldnt get these solutions to work for my situation. I ended up solving the problem in php rather than mysql. Thanks for your time! I know i learned something regardless

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM atable a
  LEFT JOIN atable b ON a.name = b.name AND a.another = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will filter out rows with an empty `another`, for which an entry with the same `name` and `value` exists that does have `another`.

```
select  *
from    YourTable yt1
where   not exists 
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.id <> yt2.id
                and yt1.name = yt2.pname
                and yt1.value = yt2.value
                and yt1.another = ''
                and yt2.another <> ''
        )
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply. Maybe i'm not understanding your solution but the problem here is I only have one table; I don't have a second table from which to join from. The first code block was the sample table and the second code block was the desired result set.

Comment: Okay, sorry for my ignorant response. I wasn't familiar with the YourTable yt1 syntax being the same as YourTable AS yt1. Okay so I have adapted your query to my situation but i'm running into the problem of it ONLY returning the single row where foo is set, in this case row 2. I need it to return all rows except row 1. Any ideas?

Comment: @Emrys: Right! I forgot ’yt1.id <> yt2.id’

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a situation where the mysql [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function would be handy.

Coalesce returns the first non-null parameter it's given. So you can use,

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(another, value) FROM MyTable;
```

this will return two columns, the id field and either the contents of the "another" column (if it is not null) or the contents of the "value" column.