# MySQL check two columns for value but with a preferred column result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, case, sql-limit

I have a MariaDB SQL table, with two different ID rows.

Id's have been imported from a previous DB version (`old_id` reference is from another table), ***as a transitional measure*** searches need to be done to find id's, with a preference for the older id value. Only **ONE** row can ever be returned .

Table:

```
new_id(PK)  |  old_id  |   data   |   more_data 
---------------------------------------------
   1        |    34    |   harge  |     spalt
   2        |     7    |   greet  |    sausages
   4        |   852    |  humbug  |    gertrude
   6        |    13    |  bloody  |   festivalz
   7        |   412    |   hello  |   fiddlests
   8        |     3    |  fraggo  |  piddlebiscs
```

`new_id` is the Primary Key.

So:

- When the page is loaded with `ID=852` it needs to return row 4
- When the page is loaded with `ID=7` it needs to return row 2
- When the page is loaded with `ID=8` it returns row 8 (because 8 does not exist in the old_id column)
- When the page is called with `ID=5` it returns nothing (no match in either column)

## What have I tried:

I have tried various ways of *qualifying* this but can't find the right syntax:

*(first attempt is silly)*

Attempted:

```
WHERE 
    table.old_id = :id 
    OR (table.new_id = :id AND table.old_id != :id) #bad one. 


WHERE 
    table.old_id = :id 
    OR (table.new_id = :id AND :id NOT IN (SELECT old_id FROM table)) 

WHERE 
    table.old_id = :id 
    OR (table.new_id = :id AND table.new_id NOT IN (SELECT old_id FROM table)) 
-- I think equivalent to the above 

WHERE CASE WHEN table.old_id = :id THEN true ELSE table.new_id = :id END

WHERE IF(table.old_id = :id, true, table.new_id = :id) 
-- I think equivalent to the above
```

## My Issue:

When an `ID` is found the SQL returns one row when it is found in the `new_id` only but otherwise it return both rows each time, when it should stop after a successful find in the `old_id`.

**What am I missing;** how can I get the SQL to check the old_id column and only if not found, then check the new_id column and only ever return one result?

## What I've checked

- [MySQL get rows but prefer one column value over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848693/mysql-get-rows-but-prefer-one-column-value-over-another)
  and
- [using CASE in the WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614573/using-case-in-the-where-clause)
- and various others that don't fit the concept; there are two successful matches, but the matches should be proritised by column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your query should always return just one record (which is how I understand your question), you can do condition ordering and `limit 1`:

```
select *
from mytable 
where :id in (old_id, new_id)
order by case when old_id = :id then 0 else 1 end
limit 1
```

If two records match, the conditional `order by` clause puts the record that matched on `old_id` on top. Then `limit 1` eliminates the other match. If only one record matches, ordering does not matter, and it is retained.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, that works on initial tests. I was hesitant to use `LIMIT` due to a belief that it negates indexing, but the query seems to run at a decent speed

Comment: Welcome @Martin! With 1 or 2 records to process, no worries about the performance of `limit`...